# floating keyboard on ipad resize screen Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: FLOATING KEYBOARD]

I added TextField, and now can not put default IPAD floating Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can disable that by setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `false` for the scaffold.

You can detect the screen width and disable that only for tablets like that:

```
Scaffod(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 650,
...
```